# How to delete record from DataBase with Spring Data Jpa @manytomany

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have Client and Notification which linked by @ManyToMany relationship like that:
Client:

```
@ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "notification_list",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "notification_ID")
    )
    @Getter @Setter
    private Set<Notification> notifications = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Notification:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "notifications", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Getter @Setter
    private Set<Client> clients = new HashSet<>();
```

I want only the link to be deleted, that is, the entry from the auth_data spanning table. How do I do this? Do I need to create a separate JpaRepository, or is it enough to simply remove the Notification from the client?

Comment: When you try it, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I added method to Client entity class:

```
public void removeNotification(Notification notification){
        this.notifications.remove(notification);
        notification.getClients().remove(this);
    }
```

Made ClientServiceIml and did this:

```
@Override
    public void removeNotifications(Client client) {
        for(Notification notification : client.getNotifications()) {
            client.removeNotification(notification);
        }
        clientRepository.save(client);
    }
```

All work fine.